# What is the difference between hyperplane and hypercube?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

They are both n-dimensional objects/constructs/shapes so where is the difference? I'd very much appreciate if you could provide a simple explanation(without compromising the real meaning of course)

Comment: A hyperplane is a generalisation of the notion of a plane in 3 dimensions. A hypercube is a generalisation of the notion of a cube in 3 dimensions. I hope you can see the difference between a plane and a cube in 3 dimensions.

Comment: In the context of linear algebra, a hyperplane subtracting one of its elements from all of them becomes a vector subspace (it is an affine subspace). A hypercube doesn't have this property.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane